# Python3における数値の分割

Tags: python, python3

最近Python3を勉強し始めた者です。
標準入力の型の指定に苦戦しております。

入力

```
12345678
```

に対して、

```
a[1]=1
a[2]=2
a[3]=...
```

とするようなコードを考えております。
過去の質問では、ジェネレータ式による

```
def gen(n):
  if n < 10:
    yield n
  else:
    for m in gen(n/10):
      yield m
    yield n%10
a = [int(i) for i in gen(数値)]
```

というものが提案されており、使用させて頂こうと考えたのですが

```
00012345...
```

のような0から始まる数字の場合には使えませんでした。
int型で0から始まるような数値に対応できるコードを作るにはどうすれば良いでしょうか。

また、応用として任意の`n*m`の行列に対して`a[1...n][1...m]`に代入できるコードももしよろしければ教えていただきたいです。

例:n=2,m=2(入力にはこれらの値の情報なし)

入力

```
12
34
```

挙動

```py
a[1][1]=1
a[2][1]=2
a[1][2]=3
a[2][2]=4
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 標準入力から、という事は `00012345` を文字列として gen 関数に渡す事になりますので、`a = [int(i) for i in gen("00012345")]` などとするとエラーになってしまいます(`'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`)。ですので、`a = [int(i) for i in gen(int("00012345"))]` とすれば良いのではないでしょうか。もしくは、`list(map(int, str(int("00012345"))))` などが考えられます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

なぜインデクスが1から始まっているんですか? ありえません。
単純な勘違いだと思って0から始まる回答にします。

前者は

```
s = '12345678'
a = [int(c) for c in s]
```

後者は

```
s = ['12', '34']
```

という入力に対して

```
a = [[int(c) for c in l] for l in s]
```

でどうぞ。

---

(追記)
後者を

```
import sys
a = [[int(c) for c in l.strip()] for l in sys.stdin]
```

と変えると標準入力から読みますよ。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。理想通りに読み込むことができました。ありがとうございました。座標を扱う際に始点を[1][1]にしておくと後の計算時に混乱せずに済むため、そうする場合が多かったのですがこれはタブーなのですね。失礼しました。

Comment: タブーなのではなくて、ただ「Pythonのリストは引数が0から始まっている」という事実があるだけです。だから1originにするのはリーズナブルでないです。